# How to get json data out of a scope after fetching data in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, fetch-api

I'm new to Vue, javascript & Web development. Using Vue, I tried to recreate the moviedb app(from Brad's 50 JS Projects in 50 Days course).

I'm getting stuck and can't get the data out of a scope.

> I've successfully retrieved data & destructured it.
> But how can I get those values out of that scope (out of setMovies function) and use it in the Vue file (html template)?

Here's my code:

**I've made the api_key private**

````
<h1>MovieDesk</h1>
<div class="hero">
 

 <!-- Search  -->
 <div class="search">
   <form @submit.prevent="handleSearch">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." />
     <button @click="handleSearch">Search</button>
   </form>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Movies -->
<div v-if="searchOn">
 <SearchedMovies />
</div>
<div v-else>
<MovieList/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
// imports-------------------

import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
import MovieList from "../components/MovieList.vue";
import SearchedMovies from "../components/SearchedMovies.vue";
import { onMounted } from "@vue/runtime-core";


export default {
components: { MovieList, SearchedMovies },

setup() {
 const searchOn = ref(false);
 const api_url = ref(
   "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=api_key&page=1"
 );
 const movies = ref([])

// getting the data ------------------------------
 onMounted(() => {
   fetch(api_url.value)
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((data) => {
       console.log(data);
       setMovies(data.results);
     });
 });

 
 function setMovies(movies) {
   movies.forEach((movie) => {
     const { title, poster_path, vote_average, overview } = movie;
     
   });
 }


 return { searchOn, setMovies };
},
};
</script> ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `setMovies` function, You can set the response in the `movies` variable and then return that `variable` from your setup.

```
function setMovies(apiResponse) {
  movies.value = apiResponse
}

return { movies };
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
const { ref, onMounted } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {
    const movies = ref([])

    onMounted(() => {
      const apiResponse = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Movie 1'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Movie 2'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Movie 3'
      }];
      setMovies(apiResponse);
    })
    
    function setMovies(res) {
      movies.value = res;
    }

    return {
      movies
    };
  }
};
Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ movies }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Catching the api response in the getMovies function helped me solve the problem. :)

Comment: @meawcoding Glad it works! Kindly do accept this answer if it helps. So that it will be helpful for other developers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'movies' to the return statement at the bottom of your code, then you should be able to render it.